# Kivy - Is there any way to bind Python functions to Widgets created in the kv language?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to create a simple Pokemon battle simulator. A trainer has 6 Pokémon, stored in a list. I have labels in the .kv file displaying the desired information.
My problem is that if I have the text property of the labels set to a Python variable:

```
text: '{}/{}'.format(root.pokemon.stats['cHealth'], root.pokemon.stats['Health'])
```

then the labels get constantly updated, but when set to a Python function:

```
text: root.pokemon.getHP()
```

with the getHP() function like:

```
def getHP(self):
    return '{}/{}'.format(self.stats['cHealth'], self.stats['Health'])
```

they do not update when the health is changed, but only when the list holding the Pokémon is changed. (eg. the order of the Pokémon is changed) Is there any way to get the binding to work when calling a function, or must all of the function calls be replaced by their return value?

Answer (score 1):

the *kv lang* will auto-bind properties that are declared in it, so can you send the stats to your function and the binding will occur :)

```
text: root.pokemon.getHP(root.pokemon.stats)
```

Each time that **stats** is changed, the function will be called.

Comment: Thank-you. This is much better than my hack of a solution to create a blank string in the App ( `blank = StringProperty('')` ) and then call updateBlank whenever I wanted the values updated.
`def updateBlank(self, blank):
        self.blank = ' '
        self.blank = ''`
The text would then look like: `text: root.pokemon.getHP() + app.blank`

Comment: @AlexanderMacKenzie You can also do hacks like text: [root.pokemon.getHP() ,root.pokemon.stats][0], but it is less pretty